# ES query for max id giving me results in scientific notation instead of long, How to fix this?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Running this query to get Aggregate for max id

```
   POST /index/_search?size=0
    {
            "size": 0,
            "aggs": {
              "maxid": {
                "max": { "field": "id"}
              }
            }
    }
```

The Result I am getting:

```
aggregations” : {
    “maxuid” : {
      “value” : 8.017010958E9
    }
  }
```

The result I want:

```
aggregations” : {
    “maxuid” : {
      “value” : 8017010958
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because all aggregations convert number fields into `double` before doing any aggregation.

You can convert the result without losing any precision upto longs with absolute value less than [2^53](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html). So you do not have to worry about it.

If you do not want to process anything after getting the result, you can do a query with sort by `id` and size `1` to get the largest id.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "size" : 1,
    "sort" : [{
         "id" : { "order" : "desc" }
    }]
}
```

[Source](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/getting-max-value-of-a-long-field-without-losing-precision/92574/2)